# Question on the Collapsing Lemma

Tags: set-theory

Say $P$ is $\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$, $\in$ is a well-founded and extensional relation(as we can see, non-empty sets in $P$ are singletons), what's the image of $ \{\{\emptyset\}\}$ via the function $\pi$ in [the Collapsing Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mostowski_collapse_lemma)?

Here's my attempt:

$\pi(\emptyset) = \emptyset$, $\pi(\{\emptyset\})=\{\emptyset\}$, since they're transitive. $\pi(\{\{\emptyset\}\})= \{\pi(z):z \in \{\{\emptyset\}\}\} =\{\{\emptyset\}\}$, which is not transitive. Something must be wrong. Does the relation $E$ on $P$ required to be transitive? I don't find such requirement in wikipedia, or Jech's textbook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your calculation is correct: $$\pi ( \{ \{ \emptyset \} \} ) = \{ \pi ( \{ \emptyset \} ) \} = \{ \{ \pi ( \emptyset ) \} \} = \{ \{ \emptyset \} \}.$$

Note that the Mostowski collapse *does not* send each set in $P$ to a transitive set, but the image of $P$ itself under the collapsing map is a transitive set.  (In your particular example, since $P$ is transitive $\pi [ P ] = P$.)

For a quite extreme example, consider $\mathbb{N}$ with the successor relation $m \mathrel{S} n$ iff $n = m + 1$.  Then we have the following:
$$\begin{align}
\pi ( 0 ) &= \{ \pi ( m ) : m \mathrel{S} 0 \} = \emptyset; \\
\pi ( 1 ) &= \{ \pi ( m ) : m \mathrel{S} 1 \} = \{ \pi ( 0 ) \} = \{ \emptyset \} \\
\pi ( 2 ) &= \{ \pi ( m ) : m \mathrel{S} 1 \} = \{ \pi ( 1 ) \} = \{ \{ \emptyset \} \} \\
&\vdots \\
\pi ( n + 1 ) &= \{ \pi ( m ) : m \mathrel{S} n+1 \} = \{ \pi ( n ) \} = \overbrace{ \{ \{ \cdots \{ }^{n+1\text{ times}} \emptyset \} \cdots \} \}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you. So if $P = \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}$, then $\pi(P)=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$.

Comment: @Metta: You're welcome (and also correct).